# Is polarization of a wave just a description of its motion in three dimensions?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, polarization, complex-numbers

Since a polarization of the wave is described by complex numbers, we can try to give that mathematical formalism geometrical meaning. With having two different axes, one imaginary and other real, it is possible to represent the motion of the wave in three dimensions as the motion of 2 waves in two planes. These two planes are being observed in three-dimensional space from the point in the third plane which is perpendicular to the two other planes. This third plane is actually a complex plane, from whose perspective these two planes are viewed as lines. This also means that the notion of a complex plane just refers to the plane which is an auxiliary construction, on which coordinates of a point in two other planes are projected. The coordinates in each plane correspond to their motion in two dimensions, parametrically described, where one of two parameters is time. This can be mathematically interpreted as a function where y=y(x).

These two equations with two variables for each one, or the lines as viewed geometrically are real and imaginary part of a complex number. Each part is showing the two-dimensional projection of a curve in three dimensions. If we can observe these two projections as independent of each other, it is possible to describe this curve in three dimensions. This is done by introduction of mathematical abstraction, a complex number, where imaginary and real part are independent of each other.

If our attention is focused only on single point in this three-dimensional world, we can just determine its location from three spatial coordinates. In other words, there are two equations sharing the connection with same parameter. Uniqueness of that parameter arises from setting the same beginning of both planar coordinates system at the place where complex plane intersects two other planes. Therefore, the solution of the equation are the coordinates of the point in three-dimensional space (x, y, z). But if we bring in another dimension to an observed object, i.e. if we make that point a line (given algebraically as the function with two variables), we get a new, fourth variable or fourth dimension. That dimension is time, from the viewpoint of a physicist.

Is this geometrical interpretation of complex number description of polarization correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interpretation is partially correct. Complex numbers are superimposition of two independent variables. Coming to electromagnetic(EM) waves we consider two components of EM wave which are perpendicular to each other. This two components do not interact with each other but they are both part of a single wave. So the vector some of these components is the magnitude of EM wave.

Complex component(i) of the EM wave is not a dimension, it is used to avoid confusion. I could have written it in terms of simple vectors but these EM components do not interact with each other. I can introduce numerous components of an EM wave.
f(x)=a(x) + i.b(x) + j.c(x) + k.d(x) + l.e(x)

The move equation is a higher order complex equation. I have number of complex planes and all are independent of each other. Fourth dimension exists in EM wave and it is time but not polarization.